# Sorting a column of text by incrementors and enumerate

Tags: python, list, loops, text

kinda new still to using python and StackOverflow. I am trying to take a text file with a list of words and iterate over it and sort that by every 1st, 2nd, and 3rd word into 3 different lists. My issue is that I can't get it to operate more than once. I think my incrementor might be incorrect.

```
shakey2 = open('/path/to/file/shakey2.txt', 'r')

col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = [] 
inc = 0
ent1, ent2, ent3 = range(3) #0, 1, 2
for en, line in enumerate(shakey2):
    l = line.strip()
    if ent1 + inc == en:
        col1.append(l)
    elif ent2 + inc == en:
        col2.append(l)
    elif ent3 + inc == en:
        col3.append(l)

    inc += 3
    continue    

shakey2.close()
print(col1, col2, col3)
```

Here is a snippet of the text file I am using:

```
artless
base-court
apple-john
bawdy
bat-fowling
baggage
beslubbering
beef-witted
barnacle
bootless
beetle-headed
bladder
churlish
boil-brained
boar-pig
cockered
clapper-clawed
bugbear
```

output:

```
(['artless'], ['base-court'], ['apple-john'])
```

Desired Output:

```
(['artless', 'bawdy', 'beslubbering'], ['base-court', 'bat-fowling', 'beef-witted'], ['apple-john', 'baggage', 'barnacle'])
```

Comment: show the **desired** output

Comment: You need to take the mod, or else the sum of those things stops being between 0 and 3. You don't even need to sum anything, I don't think. Regardless, you never reach the line after `continue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mod you can do it with ease:

```
shakey2 = open('/path/to/file/shakey2.txt', 'r')

cols = [[] for _ in range(3)]
for en, line in enumerate(shakey2):
    cols[en % 3].append(line.strip())

shakey2.close()
print(cols)
```

And if you want to unpack this list into your initial three variables:

```
col1, col2, col3 = cols
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it. I am just learning how to use enumerate. Also the list of list implementation wasn't something I considered.

Comment: you should explain it, so he understands what it is doing, and so other people who are new to python understand